# Azure Deployed Web App Trying to Locate deployed files

Tags: azure

I have a deployed web application on Azure that I seem to have lost local copied of the source files.

I'm logged onto Azure portal but can't seem to find any of the deployed files.

Anyone give me some pointers in where I should be looking to locate the deployed files.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to either connect via FTP to download all of your files or create a local Git repository and clone the site.

First thing you will need to do is reset your deployment credentials if you do not know what they are. You can do this by clicking on more commands on the web app info blade and then clicking "reset publish profile"

[image]

To connect via FTP use an ftp program such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to connect and download.

To clone your files to a local Git repo, setup your web app for continuous deployment using the following button on the web app settings blade.

[image]

You can also find detailed instructions here: [Continuous deployment using Git in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)

Both methods will let you acquire all your files that are published to the web app.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to download your files using the SCM site. Go to:
https://.scm.azurewebsites.net
and then click on CMD on the top bar.

[image]

Then you can download all of your site content in a zip. Note that the actual site content will be in the wwwroot folder in the directory "site".

[image]